# Can "via" and "through" be used with alive things in the meaning of "with the help of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can we use "via" and "through" with alive things in the meaning of "with the help of"? For example:

> These cacti were gotten by me [via/through] my dad. But for his help, I wouldn't have gotten them ever.

Comment: If you must, Ok. I got these cactuses through my Dad. I leave cacti to the scientists.

Comment: Dictionaries seem to think that _via_ is acceptable in this sense; Cambridge gives _I only found out about it via my sister._ I agree with @Lambie that the active voice is better (but I _do_ say 'cacti', and I'm not a scientist!)

Comment: But they're not often used with people in colloquial English, are they? If so, what's a better version?

Comment: via is acceptable of course but it is used more often for things than people. We did this via the press.

Comment: …and don't ever use 'gotten'. It just hurts.

Comment: "Gotten" is used by many.

Comment: _Gotten_ is used in American English, not in standard British English. I would have said that _via_ was only used of journeys, which is why I looked it up (see my comment above). _Through_ in this sense is quite widely used.

Comment: *"Gotten" is used by many* …in America. In the UK it just hurts to hear. It comes from old/middle English but went out of use in the UK so long ago as to now sound simply *wrong*, or at best dialectical & perhaps 'uneducated'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "with the help of", I'd just say "with the help of". "with the help of" can mean that whoever helped you did everything and you did nothing, or something in between: whoever helped you did some and you did some too. Or it could mean multiple people helped you and they each did some of the work and you didn't do any of it. i.e. "with the help of" has room for different meanings in how much something was of help.

"via" and "through" are more about the method by which something was done, and can sometimes carry a meaning of physical route. But it would be a strange thing to *say* "I did this 50% via X" or "I did this 50% through X"- even if that were true in some sense. At least- I have never heard someone use such a phrase, or used such a phrase myself. The physical route senses of the words can be used in contexts like "I drove here via this route" or "Can you pass this on to Mark through Matthew?" (meaning a request for someone to pass something to Matthew and instruct Matthew to pass it on to Mark).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in colloquial English people use both "via" and "through" to indicate an intermediary who helps them do or realize something (it often involves relaying information).

Here are two handy examples from online consumer reviews ([1](http://www.xposition.org/ex/21116/), [2](http://www.xposition.org/ex/23715/)):

- I found her [a life coach] **through** a colleague one day
- he [owner of a business] told us,     **via**     his manager, that it was our responsibility

Answer (score -1):

The only place where it is natural in English to use the Latin “via” is in bus or train timetables, e.g. “This train goes to London via Birmingham”.

Everywhere else use *through* or some other form of words. *Via* is the sort of pretentious term used by people trying to sound educated. They don’t and they aren’t. (And if you insist on *via*, change the informal *dad* to *father*.)

As for the rest of the sentence, it is stylistically weak using the passive. Much better to write a direct sentence, e.g.

> My dad got me these cacti. I would never have managed to get them
> without his help.

But in general you can use *through* in sentences like

> I got this genuine thingamy through someone I know at work.